# `ionic cordova run ios --emulator` fails with `An error occurred while running subprocess native-run`

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-ios

I have a Ionic Cordova application I've been working on. Recently I upgraded the cordova toolchain and now while trying to run the app on an ios emulator, it leads to an error in `native-run` after the build succeeds.

The verbose logs for `ionic cordova run ios --emulator` look like this:

```
...<build logs trimmed>...

.
.
.
Touch /Volumes/Data/ionicprojects/MyApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
    cd /Volumes/Data/ionicprojects/MyApp/platforms/ios
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Volumes/Data/ionicprojects/MyApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

No scripts found for hook "after_compile".
No scripts found for hook "after_build".
> native-run ios --app "platforms/ios/build/emulator/MyApp.app" --virtual --verbose
[native-run] 2023-09-25T04:38:49.424Z native-run Caught fatal error: IOSRunException [Error]: Path 'platforms/ios/build/emulator/MyApp.app' not found
[native-run]     at Object.run (/Volumes/Data/ionicprojects/MyApp/node_modules/native-run/dist/ios/run.js:83:15)
[native-run]     at Object.run (/Volumes/Data/ionicprojects/MyApp/node_modules/native-run/dist/ios/index.js:15:15)
[native-run]     at async Object.run (/Volumes/Data/ionicprojects/MyApp/node_modules/native-run/dist/index.js:24:13) {
[native-run]   code: undefined,
[native-run]   exitCode: 1,
[native-run]   data: undefined
[native-run] }
[native-run] ERR_UNKNOWN: Path 'platforms/ios/build/emulator/MyApp.app' not found
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.
        
        native-run ios --app "platforms/ios/build/emulator/MyApp.a... exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 5 functions +0ms
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:serve:after npm script. +2m
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +73ms
```

Note that running `native-run ios --app "platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app" --virtual --verbose` at this point successfully deploys the app onto a simulator.

Looking through the cordova-ios change logs, it seems that [default CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR overrides were removed](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2023/07/10/cordova-ios-7.0.0.html#:%7E:text=Removed%20default%20CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR%20overrides), however I *cannot* figure out how to go about migrating from this regression or any other breaking changes that might've affected me.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because cordova-ios7 change -> https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2023/07/10/cordova-ios-7.0.0.html

> ```
> build/emulator will become build/Debug-iphonesimulator
> build/device will become build/Release-iphoneos
> ```

To fix the problem since cordova fix the script,
from your ionic project path :

```
cd platforms/ios/build
ln -s Debug-iphonesimulator emulator
```

Comment: I'm aware *why* the command is failing, I have mentioned the link you posted in my question already. My question concerns how to go about fixing the fact that the toolchain is still trying to install from ```platforms/ios/build/emulator```.

Answer (score 0):

As it cordova-ios changes

```
cd platforms/ios/build

ln -s Debug-iphonesimulator emulator

ln -s Debug-iphoneos device
```

This will fix